# Website. AJAX and FIREFOX problems. I dont think Firefox likes ajax..?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Working on an AJAX website (HTML,CSS,JavaScript, AJAX, PHP, MySQL).
I have multiple javascript functions which take rows from mysql, wrap them in html tags, and embed them in the HTML (the usual usage of AJAX).

THE PROBLEM:

Everything is working perfect, except when I run the site with Firefox (for once its not InternetExplorer causing the trouble).

The site is currently in the developmental stage, so its offline, but running on the localhost (WampServer, apache, Windows XP SP3,VISTA,7).

All other cross-browser conflicts have been removed, and works perfectly on all major browsers including IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari, but I get absolutely nothing from the HTTPRequest (AJAX) if the browser is Firefox.

All browsers have the latest versions.

THE CODE:

I have a series of javascript functions, all of which are structured as follows:

```
function getDatay(){
  var a = document.getElementById( 'item' ).innerHTML;
  var ajaxRequest;
     try{//Browser Support Code:
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari:
      ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
     } catch (e){
          // code for IE6, IE5:
      try{
       ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
       try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       } catch (e){
        // Something went wrong
        alert("Your browser is not compatible - Browser Incompatibility Issue.");
        return false;
       }
      }
     }
     // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
     ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(ajaxRequest.readyState < 4){
          document.getElementById( 'theDiv' ).innerHTML = 'LOADING...';
      }
          if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                      document.getElementById( 'theDiv' ).innerHTML =  ajaxRequest.responseText;
      }
     }
     //Post vars to PHP Script and wait for response:
     var url="01_retrieve_data_7.php";
          url=url+"?a="+a;
     ajaxRequest.open("POST", url, false);//must be false here to wait for ajaxRequest to complete.
     ajaxRequest.send(null);
}
```

My money is on the final five lines of code being the cause of the problem.

Any suggestions how to get Firefox and AJAX working together are most welcome...

Comment: What is the failure mode? What happens or fails to happen?

Comment: Stop saying "AJAX" all the time. It makes you sound like the marketing department.

Comment: Also, consider using jQuery or some library, it saves you all these headaches

Comment: Why are you making a POST request with null data?

Comment: HTTPRequest delivers nothing to firefox. All other browsers recieve the HTTPRequest and display in the HTML. With firefox, i get nothing

Comment: Do you see any errors in the Error Console, or in Firebug ?

Comment: Give me his Address Who said so???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Had to post the jquery one-liner that bunch of code translates into!

```
$("#theDiv").text("LOADING...").load("01_retrieve_data_7.php?a="+$("#item").text());
```

Comment: Are you serious this one line replaces it all??

Comment: Welcome to the world of jQuery. If you want the "loading" text as well, just add `.text("LOADING...")` to the snippet.

Comment: No. You need to URL encode the data and load however many kilobytes of jQuery too.

Comment: Is this javascript, do i make a JavaScript function with this code in it?

Comment: You don't need to URL encode the data if you assume it's always URL safe (his code does that too). Even if you wanted to encode it, it's just one function call. Also those many kilobytes (a whopping 24kB gzipped) of jQuery are all code *you* don't have to write, and which will probably save him loads of code in other places as well.

Answer (score 2):

Look at that : http://translate.google.fr/translate?js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&layout=1&eotf=1&u=http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-100294-l-objet-xmlhttprequest.html&sl=fr&tl=en

Google messes up the codes so take a look at the french version for codes : http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-100294-l-objet-xmlhttprequest.html

Answer (score 0):

Before investigating your code, make sure to disable any firefox addons you've got installed.
Both ABP and Firebug are known to interfere under certain circumstances when FF tries to execute js